# Trying to calculate a value from one column by looking for the correct row in a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm not a programmer and I could not write code to save my life!

However, I have an Excel table that calculates allocated time for multiple resources. Currently, the formula I have written is not able to directly find the relevant rows so if the "Availability" row is **not** above the "Capacity" row the formula does not work as I would like it to.

The current formula I use is:

```
=IF(A8=A9, IF( B8 = "Availability", IF(D8=D9,0, IF(D8<0, -D8+D9, D9-D8)), ""), "")
```

I want the formula to look for the Resource Name and calculate the allocated hours between the "Availability" row and the "Capacity" row for each month. This formula would need to do this for each Resource Name and not duplicate results so one value for each Resource Name.

[image: View of the table I am using]

Thanks for taking the time to read this even if you are not able to help.

Comment: Did either @WhiteHat or my answer help?  If not, I know both of us would help overcome any issue pertaining to our answers.

Comment: @pnuts or took what they needed and left.   My OCD wants closure, even if it is someone else's answer that is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(B2 = "Availability",INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2 & "Capacity",A:A&B:B,0))-D2,"")
```

The problem is that capacity is not always the one directly under availability.  This is an array formula and must be confirmed by Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Put it in H2 the Formula box.  Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy down.

**One note:**  It will speed things up if instead of the entire column references; D:D,B:B and A:A, you put the actual absolute range of data; $D$2:$D$300...

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks Scott

Answer (score 0):

The `SUMPRODUCT` formula works great for this. I typically name the ranges but for this purpose, I included the first 1000 rows. This will give you the total hours for Month 1, where Resource Name = Name 1 and Category is Availability, regardless of order or the number of times each appears...

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$1000="Name 1")*($B$2:$B$1000="Availability")*($D$2:$D$1000))`

you can do the same for Capacity or if you need a difference...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$1000="Name 1")*($B$2:$B$1000="Availability")*($D$2:$D$1000))-  
SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$1000="Name 1")*($B$2:$B$1000="Capacity")*($D$2:$D$1000))
```